Getting "sqllite3.OperationError: Unable to open database file" sometimes, but other times it works fine (cx_Freeze'd file)
I made an app which uses sqllite3 database. When I run the .py file it works just fine.
Here is the code for the database:
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("game.db")
connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;")
cursor = connection.cursor()


def run(sql):
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    return [i for i in cursor]


run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (playerName TEXT PRIMARY KEY, playerPassword TEXT);")
run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (playerName REFERENCES accounts(playerName), difficulty TEXT, score INTEGER);")

I froze this program using cx_Freeze.
This is the setup.py:
import cx_Freeze
import pkgutil
from os.path import join as path_join


def get_all_packages():
    return [i.name for i in list(pkgutil.iter_modules()) if i.ispkg]  # Return name of all package


# base = "Win32GUI" allows your application to open without a console window
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('main.py', base="Win32GUI",
               target_name="Push-Ups Game", icon=path_join("Images", "Push-Ups Game Logo.ico"))]

packages = ["collections", "encodings", "importlib", "pygame", "cv2", "mediapipe",
            "math", "sqlite3", "random", "numpy", "time", "os", "re", "ctypes",
            "matplotlib", "logging", "urllib", "packaging", "PIL", "pyparsing",
            "html", "cycler", "dateutil", "kiwisolver", "json", "xml", "http", "attr", "sys"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Game",
    options={"build_exe":
             {"includes": packages,
              "excludes": [i for i in get_all_packages() if i not in packages],
              "include_files": ["Music/", "Images/", "game.db"]}},
    executables=executables
)

When I run the .exe file, weirdly the database sometimes just works fine, but occasionally it gives me the following error:
sqllite3.OperationError: Unable to open database file


I thought maybe the problem was with creating a .db file, so I removed it and ran the .exe and it generated the .db without a problem. I ran it with the .db already, also worked fine. It occasionally does not work and I could not find any correlation.
I saw a bunch of questions about this very same error, but I could not find any which had the same problem of the code sometimes working and sometimes not.
Any help is appreciated :)

Edit:
I thought it could be some permission problems so I thought the program should create the database itself (that way I thought it would have all of the permissions it needs).
I changed the code to (so that the .db file location is an absolute path):
from os import mkdir, getcwd
from os.path import join as os_join
import sqlite3

db_dir = os_join(getcwd(), "Database")

try:
    connection = sqlite3.connect(os_join(db_dir, "game.db"))
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    mkdir(db_dir)
finally:
    connection = sqlite3.connect(os_join(db_dir, "game.db"))

And deleted the .db file.
An error is still there:
cx_Freeze:Python error in main script: unable to open database file


Maybe fully path your db file?

The thing is I want to give multiple people this project and I want all of them to have their own .db file. So I cannot hardcode the location

Where or how do you import the database file?

@Hermann12 in my main.py I just do: import database

I don't have a windows machine , what if they are in a directory where they have no write permission to where game.db is going to be created ?,
here i am in the root directory on a host with no write permission and get the following:
python /tmp/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    c = sqlite3.connect("game.db")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

which looks suspiciously similar to your issue ....

I compiled the file into a .msi, I thought the download wizard would put it somewhere with permissions. (Its in Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs)

NB: Am not a windows user, so take my response with a pinch of salt. There is no path in the name 'game.db' so, my logic says that sqlite3.connect("game.db")  looks to open "game.db" for writing under the current working directory where the user started the program or if non-existing and the directory is writeable by that user create "game.db", otherwise throw the 'permission denied' these permutations should be easy enough to test. regardless of how it was packaged. , is '%USERPROFILE%' a generic token for the 'current' user in windows ?, so add that to the filename

I changed the code to have the full path (look at the EDIT section of the question). The error is still there. I don't think the path is the error (I don't know 100% though)

well, the error is now subtly different  'cx_Freeze:Python error in main script: unable to open database file' rather than the original 'sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file' . i've posted an update with a few more 'debugging' print statements and a few changes on the 'try ... except' blocks that may help you.

Thank you I will try and respond back soon with the results

from os import mkdir, getcwd
from os.path import join as os_join
import sqlite3

db_dir = os_join(getcwd(), "Database")
print(f'db_dir:{db_dir}')

try:
    print(f'initial attempt to connect to {os_join(db_dir, "game.db")}')
    connection = sqlite3.connect(os_join(db_dir, "game.db"))
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print('Operational error thrown - assuming {db_dir} or {os_join(db_dir, "game.db")} non existant')
    try:
        print(f'Attempting to create {db_dir}')
        mkdir(db_dir)
    except FileExistsError:
        print(f'{db_dir} exists, continuing');
    try:
        print(f'trying again to connect to {os_join(db_dir, "game.db")}')
        connection = sqlite3.connect(os_join(db_dir, "game.db"))
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        print(f'Too many errors encountered, aborting')
        exit(1)
   
print(f'Connected to {db_dir}, connection:{connection}')

